Burned washing machine plug
My washing machine was having a smell in the last week and we noticed now it burned the plug (see pictures) can we just change the plug? What could be the reason?
Thank you

if you had AFCI breaker it would have prevented that

Does the heat appear to have come from inside the plug near its fuse, or from inside the multibox/outlet ?

You generally don't want to run something like a washing machine on an extension cord - cause things like this happen.

The plug can be changed - don't buy a cheap one, get a quality one.
Then also replace that extension you have been using - the terminals inside often do not grip sufficiently to make a good connection.
I would look to fitting a proper socket closer to the washing machine or replacing the cable from the washing machine and making it longer. Either of these will remove the use of the extension.

I’m going to guess that the machine instructions say not to use an extension cord.

@JonCuster and how many read those? Or read that bit and promptly ignore it?

Well, nearly burning down your house might make one start doing that. Or not, their choice…

Might be able to get an entire cord.

@Huesmann think I suggested that in the last paragraph.
